# how to print this kind of data showing Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding

Tags: angular, ionic3, ionic4

this is my data of covid19 get from postman.

how to print this kind of data showing

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type
>   'object'. NgFor only supports binding

```
"Andaman and Nicobar Islands": {
  "districtData": {
    "Nicobars": {
      "notes": "",
      "active": 0,
      "confirmed": 0,
      "deceased": 0,
      "recovered": 0,
      "delta": {
        "confirmed": 0,
        "deceased": 0,
        "recovered": 0
      }
    },
    "North and Middle Andaman": {
      "notes": "",
      "active": 0,
      "confirmed": 1,
      "deceased": 0,
      "recovered": 1,
      "delta": {
        "confirmed": 0,
        "deceased": 0,
        "recovered": 0
      }
    },
    "South Andaman": {
      "notes": "",
      "active": 0,
      "confirmed": 32,
      "deceased": 0,
      "recovered": 32,
      "delta": {
        "confirmed": 0,
        "deceased": 0,
        "recovered": 0
      }
    }
  },
  `enter code here`
  "statecode": "AN"
}
```

Comment: you can use [keyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe)

Answer (score 0):

you can use KeyValuePipe for this please find attached the stackblitz example for the same.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zovcpm?file=src/app/app.component.html

But remember it's an impure pipe that may impact your app performance.

Comment: thank you very very much  sir  it's  big problem for low

Comment: I am glad that I was able to help you. If this solves this problem can you mark this as an answer?